# Invalid Gradle project configuration file?

Tags: java, eclipse, gradle, libgdx

I have a Libgdx project that worked just fine: both Desktop and Android version. I tried to add an external library (kryonet) in the gradle.build but it didn't seem to work. After messing around a bit more, Eclipse shows error in all folders, but there is no error in the code. The desktop version still runs, but the android one doesn't. In the Problems view of Eclipse there are the following errors:

```
Invalid Gradle project configuration file: .settings/org.eclipse.buildship.core.prefs   org.eclipse.buildship.core.prefs    /GameWorkspace/.settings    Unknown Gradle Project Configuration Marker
Invalid Gradle project configuration file: .settings/org.eclipse.buildship.core.prefs   org.eclipse.buildship.core.prefs    /Historia-android/.settings Unknown Gradle Project Configuration Marker
Invalid Gradle project configuration file: .settings/org.eclipse.buildship.core.prefs   org.eclipse.buildship.core.prefs    /Historia-core/.settings    Unknown Gradle Project Configuration Marker
Invalid Gradle project configuration file: .settings/org.eclipse.buildship.core.prefs   org.eclipse.buildship.core.prefs    /Historia-desktop/.settings Unknown Gradle Project Configuration Marker
```

Here is the org.eclipse.buildship.core.prefs:

```
GRADLE_FILTERS=1.0-projectRelativePath-matches-false-false-android,1.0-projectRelativePath-matches-false-false-core,1.0-projectRelativePath-matches-false-false-desktop,1.0-projectRelativePath-matches-false-false-build,1.0-projectRelativePath-matches-false-false-.gradle
eclipse.preferences.version=1
```

I tried cleaning the project and building it again and also restarting eclipse but it doesn't work.
Any idea what's wrong?
Thanks!

Comment: I have not been able to get BuildShip to work with LibGDX, but the old STS gradle plugin does work for me.

Comment: Any idea how i get back to that version of Gradle?

Comment: It's a separate Gradle plugin for Eclipse. Both can be installed simultaneously. It's the one explained in the environment setup section of the LibGDX wiki.